# Can't connect to Tor network (No SSL object)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, connection

I've been trying to connect to Tor via Tor Browser 91.6.0esr (11.0.6). I'm using bridges I managed to find by a [relay scan script](https://github.com/ValdikSS/tor-relay-scanner), but every time I try to connect to Tor, I get an error *Connection refused - [IP address of a bridge]* or *ok - [IP address of a bridge]*.

I tried connecting to Tor directly, via obfs4, meek-azure, snowflake and even requested bridges from BridgeDB about 4 or 5 times, but every method gives me either an error

> Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) ... ("general SOCKS server failure")

Or it just won't load after a successful handshake with the relay.

I have 342 bridges specified in my `torrc` if it matters.

Here is the Tor log:

```
2/17/22, 16:50:21.107 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/17/22, 16:50:21.110 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
2/17/22, 16:50:21.111 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
2/17/22, 16:50:21.368 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
2/17/22, 16:50:22.328 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/17/22, 16:50:22.328 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/17/22, 16:50:22.992 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'artikel10ber51' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.26:8443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'esojcmlin' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (50.116.35.204:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'OpenWeb4All' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (209.141.55.70:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'ooty1991' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (38.100.216.142:9050) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'CCCStuttgartBer' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.80:9000) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'debianRelay' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (138.68.9.184:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Ganthet' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (45.153.160.2:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'TheWarrior' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (23.88.108.125:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'nashorn' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (109.70.100.67:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'amatista219' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (142.47.223.219:9000) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'stvnrdgme1' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (176.123.1.67:15901) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'WhiteGoldeBlizzard' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (45.86.209.201:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'PLCNK08' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (65.108.82.43:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'moneroblack' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (140.82.16.212:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'urilikann' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (51.83.128.105:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'wombat' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (109.70.100.69:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NerdreichRelay1' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (89.58.3.114:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'dotsrcExit6' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.129.61.6:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Pikachu' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (133.242.163.153:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'TorExitVIF' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (216.239.90.19:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.155 [NOTICE] Bridge 'justRUPXicebeer01' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (194.147.84.41:5118) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'freeAmsterdam' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (45.83.232.167:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'RelaySecurity' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (172.104.52.14:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'jdtr' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (213.188.119.201:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Torchier4' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (107.189.12.251:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'chadrelay' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (144.202.61.231:9012) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'CCCStuttgartBer' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.76:9100) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Unnamed' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (45.79.42.159:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'nsk1321kme1' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (172.104.136.133:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Havoc' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (51.158.126.227:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'straUKicebeer01' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (103.175.234.144:4430) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'I' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (178.254.23.234:1137) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'PhilosofRelay' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (46.72.31.103:9090) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'bauruine' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (92.38.184.131:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'hetzDEicebeer21' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (173.208.190.13:8160) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NYCBUG1' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (66.111.2.16:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'colon' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (62.141.36.150:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'CCCStuttgartBer' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.84:9100) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'WakNETX1' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.130.47.82:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'FriendlyExitNode1' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (209.141.54.195:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'currentlane' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (148.251.91.87:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'amatista208' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (142.47.92.208:9000) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Pjotrek' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (51.89.77.31:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Unnamed' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (23.88.106.245:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'rofltor06' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (163.172.154.162:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'CCCStuttgartBer' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.73:9000) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'DragonMaw' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (85.117.235.222:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'DowntimePatrol2' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (51.81.248.194:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'mistersixt2' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (88.99.104.83:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'nar2NLicebeer38' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (195.170.172.134:4112) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Vhult' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (90.224.72.162:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'F3Netze' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.100.242:9100) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'saberrider2008' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (95.91.173.107:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Sodium' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (65.21.246.132:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'CoolComputersTOR' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (68.99.156.190:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'HanseTor' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (79.209.239.203:51901) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'maulwurf' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (109.70.100.68:8080) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'QuintexAirVPN6' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (199.249.230.117:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'tradecraft' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (45.32.230.134:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge 'tesutochuu' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (14.9.101.224:8351) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.156 [NOTICE] Bridge '0xdeadbeef' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (178.254.45.69:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'RSF12thMarch' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.102.7:80) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'PLCNK01' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (146.59.150.236:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'WoweRelay' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (23.88.6.243:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'H' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (178.254.23.18:11137) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'motor' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (46.81.13.147:9321) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'VeryKawaiiRelay2' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (132.226.207.189:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Gentoo' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (60.241.48.194:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'DFRI4' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (171.25.193.78:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'amatista087' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (142.47.88.87:9100) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'orangeneis' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (89.182.17.201:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'HeirloomReaper' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (139.99.218.3:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'TorchWood' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (144.76.3.174:9030) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Q' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (212.227.73.216:1214) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'gyror3lay' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (137.184.82.161:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'PLCNK09' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (89.58.4.49:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'inhonourofecho' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (85.164.239.249:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'GeorgiePorgiePuddin' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (202.144.174.232:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'DesPferdesSattel' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (95.217.121.18:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'deFTL' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (49.12.10.39:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'EdenNetworkRelay' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.242.181.50:38301) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'LD25' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.165.169.67:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'clicker2' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (94.16.116.137:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'CCCStuttgartBer' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.87:9000) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'vidaloca' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (162.251.117.10:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'hetzDEicebeer20' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (173.208.190.13:8158) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NoMoreGlowies' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (23.184.48.146:4200) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'voogofo1yu6eiHieghi' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (45.62.246.233:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'CCCStuttgartBer' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.64:9000) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'begonia' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (212.227.76.91:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.157 [NOTICE] Bridge 'FlashElk' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (194.32.107.220:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'F' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (178.254.9.77:11137) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'lokit04' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (89.58.17.0:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge '0xdeadbeef' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (195.90.208.37:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'cupleak' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (45.90.57.34:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'TORKeFFORG5' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (193.189.100.198:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Zeus' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (104.149.155.226:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'hetzDEicebeer36' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (173.208.190.14:8014) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'Digitalcourage4ipha' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.102.247:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'artikel10ber34' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (185.220.101.17:9443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'MikeDiaIsGone' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (80.147.218.187:8001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'RunnersRelay' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (173.230.147.188:443) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'hetzDEicebeer35' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (173.208.190.14:8192) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'NilZtheExchangeII' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (89.163.208.49:9001) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'A' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (178.254.22.186:11137) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bridge 'amatista059' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (142.47.92.59:9100) based on the configured Bridge address.
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
2/17/22, 16:50:23.158 [NOTICE] We'd like to launch a circuit to handle a connection, but we already have 32 general-purpose client circuits pending. Waiting until some finish.
2/17/22, 16:50:25.481 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 10; recommendation warn; host 742425F73781A5A50932C09EEA8A5A596995217E at 140.78.100.17:8443)
2/17/22, 16:50:25.481 [WARN] 9 connections have failed:
2/17/22, 16:50:25.481 [WARN] 9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/17/22, 16:50:25.482 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused [WSAECONNREFUSED ]; CONNECTREFUSED; count 11; recommendation warn; host 1388AB40396F57ED95BB6036E6504CE8E0F622B8 at 84.146.226.180:9001)
2/17/22, 16:50:25.482 [WARN] 10 connections have failed:
2/17/22, 16:50:25.482 [WARN] 10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
2/17/22, 16:50:25.522 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
2/17/22, 16:50:25.522 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

Answer (score 1):

you're behind a DPI - look at your logs. Use obfuscation like OBFS4